# How to export data from data grid to pdf in a flex

Tags: apache-flex, datagrid

I have a data grid in my flex application and it is scrollable. I want to export the data in it to a pdf. What is the best way to do it. I have tried with AlivePDF but all it does it take a screenshot and does not export the whole content of daa.

Comment: Include your code on what you've tried so someone can help from there.

Comment: Generically, I make a server side call which can then generate the PDF, and return a link to UI which it can then open with a navigateToURL()

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to print the datagrid see [PrintDataGrid](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=printing_5.html). Then the user can choose to print to a PDF file, for eaxample using one of the virtual pdf printers, like [pdfcreator](http://pdfcreator.forumer.it/) , that are quiete common.

In particullary you can use the `PrintDataGrid` see [How to print flex spark datagrid by using the mx PrintDataGrid? Or is there other way to achieve this without using the mx PrintDataGrid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7649244/how-to-print-flex-spark-datagrid-by-using-the-mx-printdatagrid-or-is-there-othe)